# scala multiple condition inside if and elseif

Tags: scala

Is there any better way to write below code in scala:

```
val x = r.get(c.CITY)
val y = r.get(c.COUNTRY)
val z = r.get(c.DIVISION)
val a = r.get(c.RESIDENT)

if (x == 1 || y == 1 || z == 1 ) {
  "apple"
} else if (a.nonEmpty) {
  "mango"
} else {
  "banana"
}
```

Comment: Being new to scala just trying to figure out that if there is condition like above, how we can write it in a better way?

Answer (score 4):

Your chain of `if`/`else` statements is the clearest way to express this logic because of the range of different conditions involved.

You could use a `match` but it just makes it less clear.

```
a match {
  case _ if x == 1 || y == 1 || z == 1 => "apple"
  case Some(_) => "mango"
  case _ => "banana"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can play with pattern matching

```
val res = (x, y, z, a) match {
  case (1, _, _, _) | (_, 1, _, _) | (_, _, 1, _) => false
  case (_, _, _, a) if a.nonEmpty => false
  case _ => None
}
```

and even using extractor objects to define the conditions ....

```
object FalseTupleComparison {
  def unapply(t: ( Int, Int,  Int, A)): Option[Boolean] = Some(t._1 != 1 && t._2 != 1 && t._3 != 1)
}
object EmptyTupleComparison {
  def unapply(t: ( Int, Int,  Int, A)): Option[Boolean] = Some(t._4.nonEmpty)
}

val res2 = (x, y, z, a) match {
  case FalseTupleComparison(res) => res
  case EmptyTupleComparison(res) => res
  case _ => None
}
```

Comment: @DmytroMitin when i click on upvote button it says as I have less than 15 repo so I cannot do that.

Comment: Ok, I did it for you :)

Comment: @abhi Even without 15 reputation you can accept an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative in case the number of checks increases:

```
if (List(x,y,z).contains(1)) "apple"
else if (a.nonEmpty) "mango"
else "banana"
```